# How to reference class from external jar file in spring.xml

Tags: java, configuration, jar, classpath

This is my bean define in spring.xml

```
<bean id="hello" class="test.Hello" />
```

I export class `Hello` to `hello.jar` and place it to `c:\customjar`.
And set that folder be *WINDOWS CLASSPATH*.

This is an output

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException:
Cannot find class [test.Hello] for bean with name 'hello' defined in class path resource [spring.xml];
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Hello
```

For xml file I can reference classpath by use something like this

```
<import resource="classpath:xxxxxx.xml"/>
```

But it doesn't work in my case.

---

**EDIT**

This is class sourcecode.

```
package test;

public class Hello {
    public void someMethod() {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

and this is classpath setting.

```
%CLASSPATH% = XXXXXXXX;c:\customjar\hello.jar;
```

Comment: What sould <import resource="classpath:xxxxxx.xml"/> be good for?

Comment: Spring has no special classpath handling. This is a basic classpath issue, and nothing to do with Spring.

Comment: shouldn't "%CLASSPATH% = XXXXXXXXXX;c:\customjar;" be "CLASSPATH = %CLASSPATH%;c:\customjar\hello.jar;"

Comment: Thanks @Pangea. I point classpath to jar file. But still got the same error.

Comment: have u removed the % sign prefix and suffix while seeting the classpath...run "echo %CLASSPATH%" and post the result here

Comment: .;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\lib\tools.jar;C:\axis-1_4\lib\axis.jar;C:\axis-1_4\lib\commons-discovery-0.2.jar;C:\axis-1_4\lib\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;C:\axis-1_4\lib\jaxrpc.jar;C:\axis-1_4\lib\saaj.jar;C:\axis-1_4\lib\log4j-1.2.8.jar;C:\axis-1_4\lib\xml-apis.jar;C:\axis-1_4\lib\xercesImpl.jar;C:\axis-1_4\lib\wsdl4j.jar;C:\axis-1_4\lib\qname.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\axis\WEB-INF\lib\fib.jar;C:\customjar\hello.jar;

Comment: Maybe you write it only in this style to make clear that CLASSPATH is a system variable, but when using windows the command to set the classpath is "set CLASSPATH=c:\customjar\hello.jar;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring can load classes from different jars, without any extra configuration. - For me it looks like the Hello class is really not in your running application.

Comment: Hint: when you change the environment variables in windows via the GUI, this change is not applied to running programms (and shells (CMD)). In this case you need to restart the commandline shell again.

Comment: I try to restart after set classpath but it still not work. Now I add class sourcecode and classpath setting above for more information.